# hook_breadcrumb() doesn't show breadcrumb

Tags: breadcrumbs, taxonomy-terms

Hello Drupal community,

I am trying to alter the breadcrumb in my site with the hook_breadcrumb($variables). I've used drupal_set_breadcrumb() function without any result. Here's my function in template.php :

```
/**
 * implements theme_breadcrumbs
 * @param unknown $variables
 */
function MYFUNCTION_breadcrumb($variables) {
  // On récupère les items de la page s'ils existent
  dpm($variables['breadcrumb']);
    if ($item = menu_get_item ()) {
      if (isset ( $item ['page_arguments'] )) {
        foreach ( $item ['page_arguments'] as $argument ) {
          // Keeping the name of the taxonomy in $field_name
          if (isset ( $argument->field_article_type )) {
            $field_name = "field_article_type";
          } elseif (isset ( $argument->field_type_remontee_document )) {
            $field_name = "field_type_remontee_document";
          } elseif (isset ( $argument->field_lien_type )) {
            $field_name = "field_lien_type";
          } elseif (isset ( $argument->field_type_de_contenu )) {
            $field_name = "field_type_de_contenu";
          } else {
            $field_name = "  ";
          }
          // retrieving the field and then the link to the taxoomy in the form term/taxonomy/%
          if ($field = field_get_items ( 'node', $argument, $field_name )) {
            foreach ( $field as $taxonomy ) {
              $taxo = taxonomy_term_load($taxonomy['tid']);
              $nom_taxo = $taxo->name;
              foreach ( $taxo->field_taxo_list as $taxo_link ) {
                foreach ( $taxo_link as $link ) {
                  $lien_taxo = $link ['value'];
                  $title = $item ['title'];
                  $crumbs = array ();
                  $crumbs [] = l ( t ( 'Accueil' ), '<front>' );
                  $crumbs [] = l ( $nom_taxo, $lien_taxo );
                  $crumbs [] = l ( $title );
                  dpm($crumbs);
                  drupal_set_breadcrumb ( $crumbs );
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Can anyone help ?

Thank you,

Comment: Are you rendering breadcrumbs in your template?

Comment: Yes I am, in the template.php file

Comment: There's no `hook_breadcrumb`, do you mean `theme_breadcrumb`? Can you post the full function including the definition?

Comment: Done. I used theme_breadcrumb

Comment: I do this in `hook_preprocess_page(&$variables)`. Then whatever your html for breadcrumbs is: $variables['breadcrumb'] = $html;

Comment: i done it in **themename_custom_breadcrump($vars){my code for breadcrump; drupal_set_breadcrumb($breadcrumb);
  return $breadcrumb;}** Did u checked that **$field_name** getting values..??

Comment: I checked every variable, and the array crumbs is well constructed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out how to alter the breadcrumb. The function needed to return a string

```
  function MYFUNCTION_breadcrumb($variables) {
    // On récupère les items de la page s'ils existent
    if (drupal_is_front_page ()) {
      return '';
    }
    if ($item = menu_get_item ()) {
      $title = (isset ( $item ['title'] ) ? $item ['title'] : false);
      $last = '</div>';
      $separator = '<span class="crumbs-separator">' . $variables ['crumbs_separator'] . ' </span>';
      $first_crumb = '<div class="breadcrumb"><a href="/" title="Display the homepage">Accueil</a>' . $separator;
      $key = count ( $variables ['breadcrumb'] ) - 2;
      $final_temp = ($variables ['breadcrumb'] [$key]);
      $final_crumb = ((isset ( $title ) && $title != "") ? ('<span class="crumbs-current-page">' . $title . '</span>') : ($final_temp));
      if (isset ( $item ['page_arguments'] )) {
        foreach ( $item ['page_arguments'] as $argument ) {
          // Keeping the name of the taxonomy in $field_name
          if (isset ( $argument->field_article_type )) {
            $field_name = "field_article_type";
          } elseif (isset ( $argument->field_type_remontee_document )) {
            $field_name = "field_type_remontee_document";
          } elseif (isset ( $argument->field_lien_type )) {
            $field_name = "field_lien_type";
          } elseif (isset ( $argument->field_type_de_contenu )) {
            $field_name = "field_type_de_contenu";
          } else {
            $middle_crumb = "";
          }
          // retrieving the field and then the link to the taxoomy in the form term/taxonomy/%
          if (isset ( $field_name ) && $field = field_get_items ( 'node', $argument, $field_name )) {
            foreach ( $field as $taxonomy ) {
              $taxo = taxonomy_term_load ( $taxonomy ['tid'] );
              $nom_taxo = $taxo->name;
              foreach ( $taxo->field_taxo_list as $taxo_link ) {
                foreach ( $taxo_link as $link ) {
                  $lien_taxo = $link ['value'];
                  $lien_taxo = (substr ( $lien_taxo, 0, 1 ) == "/") ? substr ( $lien_taxo, 1 ) : $lien_taxo;
                  $middle_crumb = '<a href="/' . $lien_taxo . '" title="Display ' . $nom_taxo . '">' . $nom_taxo . '</a>' . $separator;
                }
              }
            }
          }

          $crumbs = isset ( $final_crumb ) ? $first_crumb . $middle_crumb . $final_crumb . $last : '';
          // And here is returned a string
          return $crumbs;
        }
      }
    }
  }
```